# VBA DOM XML Attribute Check Statement

Tags: xml, vba, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

My program scans for an author named "Ralls, Kim" and prints out the Author name, Book Type, Book Title, and StoreLocation. What I'm trying to do now is set up a check: if the version is equal to 13, then the StoreLocation should not be printed out but it will still print all the other items.

Another item to note is that StoreLocation and StoreLocations both contain the same variable. I was not able to successfully use XPath to compare these (`Set loc = pn.SelectSingleNode("misc/PublishedAuthor/contains(name(),'StoreLocation')"`) kept giving me errors), so I ended up just using a shameful if/else statement.

```
Sub mySub()

Dim XMLFile As Variant
Dim Author As Variant
Dim athr As String, BookType As String, Title As String, StoreLocation As String
Dim AuthorArray() As String, BookTypeArray() As String, TitleArray() As     String, StoreLocationArray() As String
Dim i As Long, x As Long, j As Long, pn As Object, loc As Object, arr, ln As String, loc2 As Object

Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Dim n As IXMLDOMNode
Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set XMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFile.Load ("C:\Books.xml")

x = 1
j = 0

Set Author = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/author")
For i = 0 To (Author.Length - 1)

athr = Author(i).Text

If athr = "Ralls, Kim" Then

    Set pn = Author(i).ParentNode
    BookType = pn.getAttribute("id")
    Title = pn.getElementsByTagName("title").Item(0).nodeTypedValue

    Set loc = pn.SelectSingleNode("misc/PublishedAuthor[@id='" & athr & "']/StoreLocation")
    'not found on full name - try last name
    If loc Is Nothing Then
        'get the last name
        arr = Split(athr, ",")
        ln = Trim(arr(LBound(arr)))
        Set loc = pn.SelectSingleNode("misc/PublishedAuthor[@id='" & ln & "']/StoreLocation")
    End If

    If Not loc Is Nothing Then
        StoreLocation = loc.Text
    Else
        Set loc2 = pn.SelectSingleNode("misc/PublishedAuthor[@id='" & ln & "']/StoreLocations")
        StoreLocation = loc2.Text
    End If

    AddValue AuthorArray, athr
    AddValue BookTypeArray, BookType
    AddValue TitleArray, Title
    AddValue StoreLocationArray, StoreLocation

    j = j + 1
    x = x + 1
End If
Next

Range("A3").Resize(j, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AuthorArray)
Range("B3").Resize(j, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(BookTypeArray)
Range("C3").Resize(j, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TitleArray)
Range("D3").Resize(j, 1).Value =     WorksheetFunction.Transpose(StoreLocationArray)

End Sub

'Utility method - resize an array as needed, and add a new value
Sub AddValue(arr, v)
    Dim i As Long
    i = -1
    On Error Resume Next
    i = UBound(arr) + 1
    On Error GoTo 0
    If i = -1 Then i = 0
    ReDim Preserve arr(0 To i)
    arr(i) = v
End Sub
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<book id="Adventure" version="13">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   <price>44.95</price>
   <misc>
        <Publisher id="5691">
            <PublisherLocation>Los Angeles</PublisherLocation>
        </Publisher>
        <PublishedAuthor id="Ralls">
            <StoreLocation>N/A</StoreLocation>
        </PublishedAuthor>
    </misc>
</book>
<book id="Adventure" version="14">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   <price>5.95</price>
   <misc>
        <Publisher id="4787">
            <PublisherLocation>New York</PublisherLocation>
        </Publisher>
        <PublishedAuthor id="Ralls">
            <StoreLocations>Store B</StoreLocations>
        </PublishedAuthor>
    </misc>
</book>
<book id="Adventure" version="13">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>Mist</title>
   <price>15.95</price>
   <misc>
        <Publisher id="8101">
            <PublisherLocation>New Mexico</PublisherLocation>
        </Publisher>
        <PublishedAuthor id="Ralls">
            <StoreLocation>N/A</StoreLocation>
        </PublishedAuthor>
    </misc>
</book>
<book id="Mystery" version="14">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>Some Mystery Book</title>
   <price>9.95</price>
   <misc>
        <Publisher id="6642">
            <PublisherLocation>New York</PublisherLocation>
        </Publisher>
        <PublishedAuthor id="Ralls">
            <StoreLocation>Store D</StoreLocation>
        </PublishedAuthor>
    </misc>
</book>
</catalog>
```

So in short, if someone could please advise on two things:
1. Where should we check to see the version, put an IF statement in the very beginning? If that node didn't exist, it would cause the program to crash.
2. Why was my XPath statement in correct? `Set loc = pn.SelectSingleNode("misc/PublishedAuthor/contains(name(),'StoreLocation')"`

Appreciate any helpful comments since I'm eager to learn! Thanks.

Sample Output:

```
Ralls, Kim  Adventure   XML Developer's Guide   Version 13 Not Compatible
Ralls, Kim  Adventure   Midnight Rain           Store B
Ralls, Kim  Adventure   Mist                    Version 13 Not Compatible
Ralls, Kim  Mystery     Some Mystery Book       Store D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding question no.1, you can get the version number and use simple `if else` to alter the `StoreLocation` value. Something like this :

```
BookVersion = pn.getAttribute("version")

......

If BookVersion = "13" Then
    StoreLocation = ""
Else
    StoreLocation = loc.Text
End If
```

Regarding question no.2, your xpath is not valid in xpath 1.0. Try this way instead :

```
Set loc = pn.SelectSingleNode("misc/PublishedAuthor/*[contains(name(),'StoreLocation')]")
```

And in addition to the above, you need to explicitly tell that the selection language to be used for the `XMLFile` is xpath :

```
.....
Set XMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFile.Load ("C:\Books.xml")
XMLFile.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
.....
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. For question 1, what if the StoreLocation node doesn't exist and the version node does?

Comment: What if we wanted to include an OR operator while also checking the Author name variable, would something like this work? `Set loc = pn.SelectSingleNode("misc/PublishedAuthor[@id='" & ln & "']/StoreLocation" | "misc/PublishedAuthor[@id='" & ln & "']/StoreLocations")` Is there a limit to the number of XPath parameters or can we literally use contains/starts-with() as often as needed? `Set loc = pn.SelectSingleNode("misc/PublishedAuthor[@id='" & ln & "']/*[starts-with(name(),'StoreLocation')]")` Sorry for all the questions, just really curious and fascinated by this :)

Comment: @NRH both are valid and should work (if I understand you correctly), and no limit to the number of xpath parameters AFAIK. To satisfy your upcoming curiosities about xpath, I'd suggest to play around with in an xpath tools (this is [one of them](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html), or google to find plenty alternative and pick anyone you like). Paste your XML there and try any xpath query you can think of without hassle, before actually using it in your VBA codes

Comment: That's a wonderful resource, thank you! If you don't mind, please take a look at this and give me your opinion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722275/vba-xml-dom-search-for-an-item-that-may-not-always-exist