# VBA XML DOM Search for an item that may not always exist

Tags: xml, vba, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

How do you create a loop for a node that might not always be part of its parent - while parsing data for other nodes?

Assume you have a very large file with several of these items, but for simplicity let's use this XML (notice the first 'book id' does not have the node we want, so our loop already fails):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<book id="Adventure" ISBN="00113" version="13">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   <price>44.95</price>
   <misc>
        <editor id="9B">
            <editorBrand>Partial Edit</editorBrand>
            <editorEmphasis>Minimal</editorEmphasis>
        </editor>
   </misc>
</book>
<book id="Adventure" ISBN="00114" version="14">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   <price>5.95</price>
   <misc>
        <Publisher id="5691">
            <PublisherLocation>Los Angeles</PublisherLocation>
        </Publisher>
        <PublishedAuthor id="Ralls">
            <StoreLocation>Store A/8</StoreLocation>
            <seriesTitle>AAA</seriesTitle>
                <store id="8">
                    <copies>26</copies>
                </store>
    </misc>
</book>
<book id="Adventure" ISBN="00115" version="14">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>Mist</title>
   <price>15.95</price>
   <misc>
        <Publisher id="8101">
            <PublisherLocation>New Mexico</PublisherLocation>
        </Publisher>
        <PublishedAuthor id="Ralls">
            <StoreLocation>Market C/13</StoreLocation>
            <seriesTitle>BBB</seriesTitle>
                <store id="9">
                    <copies>150</copies>
                </store>
                <store id="13">
                    <copies>60</copies>
                </store>
        </PublishedAuthor>
    </misc>
</book>
<book id="Mystery" ISBN="00116" version="13">
   <author>Bill, Simmons</author>
   <title>NBA Insider</title>
   <price>16.99</price>
   <misc>
        <editor id="11N">
            <editorBrand>Full Edit</editorBrand>
            <editorEmphasis>Full</editorEmphasis>
        </editor>
    </misc>
</book>
</catalog>
```

Our VBA Code:

```
Sub mySub()

Dim XMLFile As Variant
Dim seriesTitle As Variant
Dim series As String, Author As String, Title As String, StoreLocation As String
Dim ISBN As String, copies As String, storelc As String
Dim seriesArray() As String, AuthorArray() As String, BookTypeArray() As String, TitleArray() As String
Dim StoreLocationArray() As String, ISBNArray() As String, copiesArray() As String
Dim i As Long, x As Long, j As Long, pn As Object, loc As Object, arr, ln As String, loc2 As Object

Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Dim n As IXMLDOMNode
Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set XMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFile.Load ("C:\Books.xml")
XMLFile.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

x = 1
j = 0

Set seriesTitle = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/misc/PublishedAuthor/seriesTitle")
For i = 0 To (seriesTitle.Length - 1)

series = seriesTitle(i).Text
storelc = seriesTitle(i).SelectSingleNode("store/copies").Text

If series = "AAA" Or series = "BBB" Then

    Set pn = seriesTitle(i).ParentNode
    StoreLocation = pn.getElementsByTagName("StoreLocation").Item(0).nodeTypedValue
    Author = pn.ParentNode.ParentNode.getElementsByTagName("author").Item(0).nodeTypedValue
    Title = pn.ParentNode.ParentNode.getElementsByTagName("title").Item(0).nodeTypedValue
    ISBN = pn.ParentNode.ParentNode.getAttribute("ISBN")

    Set loc = pn.SelectSingleNode("seriesTitle/store[@id='" & storelc & "']/copies")
    If loc Is Nothing Then
        arr = Split(storelc, "/")
        ln = Trim(arr(UBound(arr)))
        Set loc = pn.SelectSingleNode("seriesTitle/store[@id='" & ln & "']/copies")
    End If

    If Not loc Is Nothing Then
        copies = loc.Text
    Else
        copies = "?"
    End If

    AddValue seriesArray, series
    AddValue AuthorArray, Author
    AddValue TitleArray, Title
    AddValue StoreLocationArray, StoreLocation
    AddValue ISBNArray, ISBN
    AddValue copiesArray, copies

    j = j + 1
    x = x + 1
End If
Next

Range("A3").Resize(j, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AuthorArray)
Range("B3").Resize(j, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(TitleArray)
Range("C3").Resize(j, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ISBNArray)
Range("D3").Resize(j, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(seriesArray)
Range("E3").Resize(j, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(StoreLocationArray)
Range("F3").Resize(j, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(copiesArray)

End Sub

'Utility method - resize an array as needed, and add a new value

Sub AddValue(arr, v)
    Dim i As Long
    i = -1
    On Error Resume Next
    i = UBound(arr) + 1
    On Error GoTo 0
    If i = -1 Then i = 0
    ReDim Preserve arr(0 To i)
    arr(i) = v
End Sub
```

My goal is to search for "seriesTitle". So I will specifically create a For loop that searches for the length of items found and then parse the "seriesTitle" along with ISBN, StoreLocation, Author, Book Title, and copies.

1. If seriesTitle exists - it's version 14 then - I want to print out seriesTitle, ISBN, StoreLocation, Author, Book Title, and copies.
2. If seriesTitle does NOT exist - it's version 13 then - I only want to print the ISBN, Author, and Book Title.

But the issue is that for each 'book id' that exists, there isn't necessarily a "seriesTitle" - the only relationship we can draw is that when the 'version=13' there is no seriesTitle.

- How would you loop through an entire document if you don't have an object to create a For loop search with? And when "seriesTitle" doesn't exist, how would you continue to add items to the ISBN, Author, and Book Title array?

Thank you for teaching me with any helpful comments and suggestions!

Comment: Why not *start* with a collection of <book> nodes and loop over that?  That would seem to be the most straightforward way of approaching this: you can check the book's version attribute and work from that when deciding whether to look for the seriesTitle node.

Comment: @TimWilliams I did have an attempt where I created a For loop that searched for books and then another For loop inside that would filter nodes that I needed, but I ended up literally printing out a loop of a loop x the amount of books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, it seems like you would be better off just looping over all of the `<book>` elements and reading their child nodes for the required values, rather than navigating up and down the DOM tree quite so much.

```
Sub Tester()

Dim d As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim bks As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim bk As Object
Dim cat As Object, sertitle
Dim isbn, storeLoc, auth, seriesTitle, vsn, copies, title

    d.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    d.LoadXML Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

    Set bks = d.SelectNodes("/catalog/book")
    For Each bk In bks

        vsn = bk.getAttribute("version")
        isbn = bk.getAttribute("ISBN")
        title = GetTextSafely(bk, "title")
        storeLoc = GetTextSafely(bk, "misc/PublishedAuthor/StoreLocation")
        seriesTitle = GetTextSafely(bk, "misc/PublishedAuthor/seriesTitle")
        auth = GetTextSafely(bk, "author")

        copies = "??" '  I'm unclear exactly what you're doing here....

        Debug.Print vsn, isbn, storeLoc, seriesTitle, auth, title, copies

    Next bk

End Sub

'utility function: get a node's value if it exists
Function GetTextSafely(el As Object, path As String)
    Dim nd, rv
    Set nd = el.SelectSingleNode(path)
    If Not nd Is Nothing Then rv = nd.nodeTypedValue
    GetTextSafely = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `For Each bk In bks` and say `For i=0 To (bks.length - 1)`? Is one more ideal depending on the conditions?

Comment: They both do the same thing. Sometimes if you need a counter inside the loop it's more convenient to use the `For i = ...` version

Answer (score 1):

First your xml contains an error.  You are missing the closing tag for .  See new XML below

```css
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
  <book id="Adventure" ISBN="00113" version="13">
    <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
    <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
    <price>44.95</price>
    <misc>
      <editor id="9B">
        <editorBrand>Partial Edit</editorBrand>
        <editorEmphasis>Minimal</editorEmphasis>
      </editor>
    </misc>
  </book>
  <book id="Adventure" ISBN="00114" version="14">
    <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
    <title>Midnight Rain</title>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <misc>
      <Publisher id="5691">
        <PublisherLocation>Los Angeles</PublisherLocation>
      </Publisher>
      <PublishedAuthor id="Ralls">
        <StoreLocation>Store A/8</StoreLocation>
        <seriesTitle>AAA</seriesTitle>
        <store id="8">
          <copies>26</copies>
        </store>
      </PublishedAuthor>
      </misc>
  </book>
  <book id="Adventure" ISBN="00115" version="14">
    <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
    <title>Mist</title>
    <price>15.95</price>
    <misc>
      <Publisher id="8101">
        <PublisherLocation>New Mexico</PublisherLocation>
      </Publisher>
      <PublishedAuthor id="Ralls">
        <StoreLocation>Market C/13</StoreLocation>
        <seriesTitle>BBB</seriesTitle>
        <store id="9">
          <copies>150</copies>
        </store>
        <store id="13">
          <copies>60</copies>
        </store>
      </PublishedAuthor>
    </misc>
  </book>
  <book id="Mystery" ISBN="00116" version="13">
    <author>Bill, Simmons</author>
    <title>NBA Insider</title>
    <price>16.99</price>
    <misc>
      <editor id="11N">
        <editorBrand>Full Edit</editorBrand>
        <editorEmphasis>Full</editorEmphasis>
      </editor>
    </misc>
  </book>
</catalog>​
```

When ever you have a multi level object and levels are missing you must search by one level at a time.  Every book has a "misc" tag.  So you first must enumerate books by "misc".  Then test if the child exists.

```css
Set misc = XMLFile.SelectNodes("catalog/book/misc")
For a = 0 To (misc.Length - 1)
   Set publishedAuthor = XMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/misc/PublishedAuthor/seriesTitle")
   If Not publishedAuthor Is Nothing Then

   End If
Next a
```

Comment: Thanks. But if there are hundreds of <misc> in a file, is that not really efficient? Because then I would have to search such a broad spectrum and keep trying to refine it.

Comment: You have filter the nodes you are looking for in misc.  All you really want are nodes with PublishedAuthors.  Right?  Using XML.Linq can help perform the filtering.  But you still have to come up with a valid set of filters.

Comment: @jweng I've never heard of XML.Linq but I'll look into that. Thank you.