# Read XML Attribute VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xdoc

I am trying to get the attribute of a single node in VBA, but can't manage it using DOM

The XML looks like following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <soap:Body>
             <GetUserInfoResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
                <GetUserInfoResult>
                   <GetUserInfo>
                      <User ID="16" Name="David" LoginName="login" Email="" Notes="" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" />
                      <User ID="17" Name="Gal" LoginName="login" Email="" Notes="" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" />
                      <User ID="18" Name="Netzer" LoginName="login" Email="" Notes="" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" />
                      <User ID="3" Name="More" LoginName="login" Email="" Notes="" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" />
                      <User ID="20" Name="Alon" LoginName="login" Email="" Notes="" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" />
                      <User ID="21" Name="Dan" LoginName="login" Email="" Notes="" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" />
                      <User ID="708" Name="Yaron" LoginName="login" Email="" Notes="" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" />
                </GetUserInfo>
             </GetUserInfoResult>
          </GetUserInfoResponse>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

I am basically just trying to get the value of the ID attribute. Any help would be appreciated.

this is same question as in the following link:
[Read XML Attribute VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297068/read-xml-attribute-vba)
 with small change ! as you can see in XML file there is more then one USER 
so the following answer doesn't fit,

```
Try:

(Include a reference to Microsoft XML v3, I saved your xml to a file on my desktop)

    Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument30
    Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument30
    xmlDoc.Load ("C:\users\jon\desktop\test.xml")

    Dim id As String
    id = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//GetUserInfo/User").Attributes.getNamedItem("ID").Text
```

how can i know the name of user that his ID  is "21"?

really be glad if someone can help me

Comment: Get the `GetUserInfo` node first, then select from the subnodes.

Comment: @Comintern I don't get it, can you please explain your answer? or give an example ?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29726379/4088852).

Comment: 10X for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Dim oDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
Dim el As Object
Dim XML As String

XML = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value 'for testing....

oDoc.validateOnParse = True
oDoc.LoadXML XML  '<< using LoadXML to load from a string
                  '   use Load if you're reading from a file

'select the User node with ID=21
Set el = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("//GetUserInfo/User[@ID=""21""]")

If Not el Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print el.getAttribute("Name")
Else
    Debug.Print "user id not found!"
End If
```

Comment: oDoc.LoadXML XML --->oDoc.Load XML

Comment: My answer doesn't need editing: I'm using your XML stored in a worksheet cell and using `LoadXML` to load the document from that string.  `Load` is correct if you want to load the document from a file.